Load functions in a new blocks in org-mode
To shorten the content, I write a function in a block and I want the function to be used in several other blocks. Is there any other method other than the session method shown in the following example?
#+begin_src R :session "AA" 
  add <- function(x,y){return(2*(x+y))}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:

#+begin_src R :session "AA" :var A=1 B=5
  add(A,B)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 12

#+begin_src R :session "AA" :var A=2 B=3
  add(A,B)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 10



You can use header-args:R to define the session arg for all the code blocks - see Header arguments in Org mode properties.
